# Send UDP packet to local port

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using the following C# code to send a packet to a local port.

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9000);
byte[] send_buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test message");
sock.SendTo(send_buffer, endPoint);
```

How can I do the same in a few calls in Actionscript? I don't need any two way communication or overhead: just as little code as possible to send a packet of text to a UDP server that I'm running in a C# app.

I've tried creating a javascript function to accept an ExternalInterface call and sending it on from Javascript with Node.js, but I think there might be an easier way of doing it.

```
//FLASH
    ExternalInterface.call("sendToUDP", "Test message");

//HTML
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function sendToUDP(message) 
    { 
        //Some code to send a UDP packet from Javascript
    } 
    </script>
```

Comment: The UDP is only available with Adobe Air.
[Reference Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`DatagramSocket`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html) in AIR, this should be the equivalent AS3 to your C# code:

```
var socket:DatagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
var address:String = "127.0.0.1", port:int = 9000;
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeUTFBytes("Test message");
socket.send(bytes, 0, 0, address, port);
```